# how to create log for mail function in laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, email

I want to create log file for instead of sending.I referred and change `mail_driver=log` in .`env` file. but I doesn't create any log file in laravel 5.3.
How to create log file in laravel 5.3 and where to find that log file

```
.env
 MAIL_DRIVER=log
 MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
 MAIL_PORT=2525
 MAIL_USERNAME=null
 MAIL_PASSWORD=null
 MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

Comment: Laravel log file is in `storage/logs` directory. Did you check there ?

Comment: file is in storage/logs but mail log is not there

Comment: Can you update your question and paste your mail related code?

Answer (score 1):

The log file you are looking is located at`./storage/logs/laravel.log`

May be the file could looks full of annoying content so i recommend clear that log first... Or change the log storage configuration in `config/app.php`

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/errors#log-storage

Hope you can find it!